# was made a verbal offer, then never heard from them

Tags: job-offer

I was contacted nearly two months ago about a job.  Had the interview, two weeks later was asked if I were to be offered the job, and if I were to except, when could I start?  I told them, then was told I would receive an offer letter soon if not that day.  Two and a half more weeks passed, no offer letter, but this time I was asked if I would accept a lower amount of money than what I said I wanted (it was only $5000 less and we all know that the figure you give them will go down, so the answer was yes).  Then I was told, ok, I will be back to you soon. Another week and a half passes and I get an email saying they are prepared to offer me the job at the salary agreed upon, and the reason for the delay is they gave someone else the first job because they could start asap, but they had a second opening and this one was for the dollar amount and would I accept it.  I called to clarify a few things, then said yes.  I was then told I would get a formal offer letter later that day.  I also responded to the email stating yes, I would accept it and look forward to starting.  They also responded to the email stating they would send an offer letter that day.

It has now been another five days and crickets. At what point is this a warning sign that this company is a mess, or is this normal?  Did they again give the job to someone else and now aren't telling me as they did the first time around and kept promising the offer was being sent "today" and "soon" when in fact they gave it to someone else?

Comment: It seems goofy already, but lots of small companies are like that (and lots of very big companies, too). Have you tried to call them, since email is the worst way to communicate when deadlines loom? If you call, and leave a message, and they don't return it within a day, then that is the point that you should run away and never look back.

Comment: Chad, not even close. I'm not looking to take legal action for not sending a formal offer.  My questions is whether or not this is normal, or should be a warning sign.

Comment: Thanks Kent.  I have not stopped interviewing elsewhere, and you are right, if they don't return my call, time to walk away even if I think I want the job.

Answer (score 3):

The employer seems to be very unorganised. Giving the first job to someone else I would take as a warning signal and unless I was desperate for work I wouldn't have contemplated the second offer, the second issue of leaving you hanging for 5 days is just rude (my opinion). Don't stop looking for another job.

Contact them only if you really want this one. Politely ask when you can expect the job offer in writing, listen patiently to whatever excuse is given, and if they don't front up, forget them.